How does the pvarfeols function from the R panelvar package handle fixed effects?
I have been using the pvarfeols function (Fixed Effects Estimator for PVAR Model) from the R panelvar package. It seems like the pvargmm function is a primary feature of the panelvar package but I opted not to use it due to the relatively large size of the data.
My panel data, which is unbalanced, consists of 3 columns (excluding id and time) with approximately 7.6 million observations.
I want to conduct a panel vector autoregression (VAR) analysis on three variables with five lags, incorporating the following controls: firm fixed effects, day fixed effects, and time (clock time) fixed effects.
In the package documentation for the pvarfeols function, I noticed that the 'demean' option is available for transformation. For example:
pvarfeols(
  dependent_vars,
  lags,
  exog_vars,
  transformation = c("demean"),
  data,
  panel_identifier = c(1, 2)
)

However, I am curious about how the 'demean' option is defined in the function.
Does this option subtract a time-series average from each data point to control for firm fixed effects? Or does it also subtract a cross-sectional average from each data point?
Using ChatGPT, I discovered that there might be more options than just 'demean'.
For instance, ChatGPT suggested that 'time-demean' is also available although I am not sure if this is truly the case. When I used the 'time-demean' option, the results of the pvarfeols function were the same as when using the 'demean' option.
Could I get some insights on how the pvarfeols function handles fixed effects?

Using ChatGPT for finding out how specific functions in R libraries work is really not advisable; if it isn't in the documentation, after all, how would ChatGPT "know"?  If you look at the code itself, you'll see that demeaning is hardcoded in pvarfeols, there is no other option.

@jbowman I agree with you. Thank you very much for your advice.

The relevant line (there is only one) of R code from the pvarfeols function is:
       Set_Vars <- cbind(Set_Vars, 
                         do.call(rbind, mapply(function(i) panel_demean(Set_Vars[Set_Vars$category == 
            categories[i], ], demean),
                                        1:length(categories), SIMPLIFY = FALSE)))

Unfortunately, we have no visibility into the panel_demean function, but it is pretty clear from what is passed that the demeaning is based on the means of the variables within each category.
The categories are the unique values of the variables passed to the function in the panel_identifier parameter, which accepts either names (text) or positions (integer) values:
if (is.numeric(panel_identifier)) {
        Set_Vars <- data[, c(colnames(data)[panel_identifier], 
            required_vars)]
    }
    else {
        Set_Vars <- data[, c(panel_identifier, required_vars)]
    }

and, a little farther down in the code:
categories <- sort(unique(Set_Vars[, 1]))


Thank you very much @jbowman! I looked into the source code and found out that panel_demean function is defined at the very bottom of https://rdrr.io/cran/panelvar/src/R/helper_functions.R.
Interestingly, the transformation parameter is not used within this function.
So I guess it doesn't control for time-fixed effects.

Good for you, @catin!  It occurred to me to look there this morning (PST) but you beat me to it!  That's what I get for running a Windows machine, where packages are binary by default and it's a little more work to see the underlying code.
